# Probability that 3 is a person's phone number.

Tags: probability

What is the probability that any digit in a ten-digit phone number is three. I know that there is a 10% that any one given digit could be 3, but I would like to know what the probability of having a three someone in the ten-digit number.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ What is the probability of there NOT being a three in a random phone number?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about JUST one three? 
Because the probability of there being JUST ONE 3 is
P(not 3)*P(not 3)*P(not 3)*P(not 3)*P(not 3)*P(not 3)*P(not 3)*P(not 3)*P(not 3)*P(3)

(9/10)^9*(1/10) = .0387420489  So, there is a 3.87420489 % chance that a 10 digit number has exactly one 3 in it.

Comment: @user106494 does this answer your quesiton?